# Why do these apples have no nutritional value?

Tags: visual, knowledge, science

[image: An orchard, and a box of apples on the ground labelled "‮C.RIGAUD‬‭"]

These apples have no nutritional value. Why?

Comment: Because [they're only pictures of apples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)

Comment: Because they haven't been eaten yet?

Comment: @paste Okay, technically yes, but I mean what the picture represents. (I suppose that's a valid answer though.)

Comment: @JoeZ. Things have nutritional value *before* their digested, not after.

Comment: @PyRulez I know; that's why I didn't post a real answer :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, and nice puzzle!

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks (btw, is it common that a puzzle won't be well received until it has an answer? (It was sitting at -1 until Millikan figured it out.))

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The mirror reflection of the image change the handedness of the molecules.  They can then not be digested.

Comment: Should I have made it subtler? :)

Comment: [Related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_chirality_in_popular_fiction) (spoiler alert, naturally).

Comment: To be fair, it should be noted that if there were people in the picture then the apples would have nutritional value to them.

Comment: I was going to suggest that somebody held the stencil backwards when they labeled that crate.  It's not necessarily the entire image that's flipped...

Answer (score 1):

Either something with the mirroring of the image .. or the text on the box is spelled the same as "you rig odd"? (whatever that means, not a native speaker)

Comment: "your i go?" .. sorry, have no clue, but this is fun :)

Comment: Nope, neither "you rig odd" or "your i go".